# How to write a modular JavaScript application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, sproutcore, javascriptmvc

I am planning to rewrite an existing Silverlight application using HTML, JavaScript and CSS. This will be a rich internet application connecting to a server only for data (JSON based web services) - so there will be no server-side presentation framework such as JSP or ASP.NET. The application consists of about 8 screens, most of them in a tabbed layout. The question is...

What is the best way to write such an application in a modular fashion? I would like to write the individual screens as standalone modules communicating with each other only via events. I would also like to use some sort of an MVC framework to decouple the presentation layer from the model.

Any thoughts on which frameworks I should look at? Have you had a good experience using them? I am starting to look at [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/), [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/) and [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/). Am I missing anything that is worth considering?

Thanks in advance for your time.

P.S. If you'd like to see the application that I am trying to rewrite, an online demo is available [here](http://archfirst.org/apps/bfclient-silverlight/bullsfirst.html) - it is a realistic trading application built for learning and comparing technologies.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't yet had a chance to try SproutCore, but I hear good things about it and want to look into it at some point. I would recommend trying out at least Backbone and Sproutcore to see which of the two fits your needs and your programming style better.

I do a lot of work with Backbone, and what your suggesting sounds like it would be a very easy fit with backbone. I follow an event-driven architecture with my backbone apps and I find it works very well. it keeps code clean and separated, and allows me to add functionality easily by binding to events that my objects raise.

there are a lot of great tutorials and screencasts for backbone out there, too. here a few of them that should hopefully give you some of the information you need (including my own blog posts):

- http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/category/backbone/
- http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/ (introduce event-driven apps in backbone)
- http://joeybeninghove.com/2011/08/16/backbone-screencast-introduction-views/
- http://peepcode.com/products/backbone-js ($)
- http://tekpub.com/view/mvc3/6 ($ and specific to ASP.NET MVC integration)

again, don't just pick one and never look back. it's worth your time to at least do some simple trial applications in backbone and sproutcore, if not additional frameworks.

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Derick. This is very useful. I will be checking out the links.

Answer (score 2):

With Sproutcore, you can create so-called frameworks so separate your application.  Every SC project has a `frameworks` directory, you just add a directory for your custom frameworks, and include the frameworks in your buildfile.

It's not a bad idea with SC to at least separate your Model layer into its own framework, for loose coupling and testing purposes (SC is heavily MVC). It might make sense to separate your screens into their own frameworks, depending on how beefy they are.  One of the benefits of this approach is you can reuse your frameworks in other projects if needed.

SC also includes a robust Statechart mechanism, so using custom events is quite natural, and because of the statecharts its relatively easy to insure that the events are handled only when the app is in the right state.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Relay framework? Your write your individual screens as standalone modules and use relay's event system to link them together.

http://relay.github.com